# Write to Event log from BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, event-log

When I try to execute an orchestration with something like `EventLog.WriteEntry("MyEsb", "Msg");` in Expression shape, I get the exception `The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security.` Why?
I'm running Win 7 64bit if this makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution. As the error says, *"To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique. Inaccessible logs: Security."* So even though BizTalk User account has enough rights to write to the eventlog it has no rights to read EventLog\Security log as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) in a Note in the Remarks section:

> The reason for this requirement is that all event logs, including security, must be searched to determine whether the event source is unique. Starting with Windows Vista, users do not have permission to access the security log; therefore, a SecurityException is thrown.

So I just granted a Read Access to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Security` for BizTalk User and the problem was solved.

Comment: After granting my host account access to that key in RegEdit, I get: "Requested registry access is not allowed." at run time, in an Event Log message.

Answer (score 5):

When you write the event log from any application, the event source needs to be already created, or the application itself will try to create it before writing to it. Unfortunately, creating an event source is an action which requires local admin priveledges.

So you can do two things:

1. pre-create the event source
2. make sure the user which your biztalk host is running as is in local admins (bad)

To pre-create the event source is a nicer option. You can do this via the powershell command

```
New-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "MyEsb"
```

Comment: The problem was that BizTalk User had no read access to the Security log, see my answer.

Comment: In the past, I have seen the lack of an event source cause the exact error given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Might seem like I'm stating the obvious but has the **BizTalk User** got permission to write to the Eventlog? That is, the account of the Host Instance running the Orchestration.

You'll probably find that it hasn't.

HTH

Comment: It has, but still no luck. See my answer.